# IE10 - Strange Form Submission Issue

Tags: javascript, html, submit, internet-explorer-10, onfocus

Please see the code snippet below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name="editProfileForm" method="post" action="profileDataCollection.do">
    <input type="text" id="credit-card" name="credit-card" onfocus="unmaskCC(this);" onblur="maskCC(this);" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ccValue" value=""/>
    <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function unmaskCC(field){
    /*code for unmasking credit card field*/
    alert("unmask called"); /*For demo purpose introduced an alert*/
}
function maskCC(field){
    /*code for masking the credit card field*/
    alert("mask called"); /*For demo purpose introduced an alert*/
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem Description: I have the above code in one of my JSP pages. When this page is rendered in Internet Explorer 10, I see a strange problem. When I hit the continue button (i.e. form's submit button), the onfocus of the credit-card field is automatically triggered and the function "unmaskCC" is called. The form does not submit. **This problem occurs only in IE10.**

I have tested the same page with Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari (Desktop, Tablet, Mobile)
and everywhere it seems to be working fine.

I initially thought that clicking submit is causing "event bubbling", but that cannot happen, since continue button is a sibling of credit-card field.

**Also Note:** I have the workaround for this issue i.e. changing the `button type="button"` and then submitting the form via onclick javascript i.e. 
`document.getElementById("editProfileForm").submit();` which works fine as expected.

But I am unable to understand what is causing the `<button type="submit">` to not work as expected.

I am going crazy with this IE10 specific issue. Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ................................

Answer (score 2):

The problem (which is reproducible in IE 11, too) seems to be caused by a problem in event handling in IE: when you click on the submit button, the text input field first loses focus, so its `onblur` handler is triggered, causing a modal window to appear, and here IE somehow loses the information that the input button had been clicked on.

If you replace `alert` e.g. by `console.log`, the problem does not occur. In your real code, you probably have something in the `onblur` event handler that makes some element or widget get focus, similarly resulting in IE losing track of what it was doing.