# Setting value via Javascript sets focus to textbox in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I have the following Textbox

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSeleID" Columns="12" MaxLength="14" 
             onfocus="javascript:SetSearchText();" 
             onchange="javascript:SetSearchText();"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="REV_SeleID" runat="server" 
             ErrorMessage="ID must contain up to 12 numbers." 
             Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSeleID" 
             ValidationExpression="ID...|^\s*(\d{1,12}|\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{1}-\d{4}|\d{1}-\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4})\s*$" CssClass="ValidationError" SetFocusOnError="True">(!)
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

and the below javascript :

```
function SetSearchText() {
var Tbox = document.getElementById("<%=txtSeleID.ClientID%>");
if (Tbox.value == "ID...") {
    Tbox.value = "";
    Tbox.className = "";
}
}
$(document).ready(function () {
var Tbox = document.getElementById("<%=txtSeleID.ClientID%>");
if (Tbox.value.length == 0) {
    Tbox.className = "quickEnter";
    Tbox.value = "ID...";
}
if (Tbox.value == "ID...") 
    Tbox.className = "quickEnter";
});
```

Here is the button:

```
<asp:ImageButton EnableViewState="false" id="SubmitBtn" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl='<%#Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/btn_submit.gif")%>' 
    onclick="Submit_Click" ToolTip="Submit" />
```

The issue is that when I click on my submit button, it calls the `SetSearchText()` function and sets the value to `""`.  In IE 10, it sets the focus to this textbox and I have to hit my submit button again to get it to submit.

If I comment out the setting of the value, the focus issue doesn't occur.

How can I prevent the browser from forcing a focus to my textbox when attempting to submit?

EDIT: Added the regular expression validator to the code section.

EDIT: I found [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215022/ie10-strange-form-submission-issue) that was having a similar issue, but I don't see a resolution.  In this one, he is using html tags.  I'm using ASP tags so I can't as easily change the input type.

Comment: you want to call this function by submit button then why you have used onfocus and onchange on textbox

Comment: I don't want it on submit.  It's setting focus automatically when I click my submit button and preventing my postback click event.  It only happens in IE10.  Possibly 9, haven't tested in 9

Comment: show your button html code and why do you need onchange="javascript:SetSearchText();" in the textbox.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,  I'll get the button code, but I'm 99% sure that the cause isn't there.  I've had some time to think about the issue, and there is a regularexpressionvalidator on the textbox.  I believe this might be the cause of the re-focus.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about why the onchange event is there.  I'll have to investigate.  I took this code over from someone else to fix.

Comment: I went back and verified the issue does not occur in IE9.  It is specific to IE10 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a workaround by checking for the browser version.  If IE 10/11, I don't add the text to the input field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lexidTbox = document.getElementById("<%=txtSeleID.ClientID%>");
    //workaround for IE10/11 issue
    var showLegalText = true;

// IF THE BROWSER IS IE10
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") !== -1) {
    showLegalText = false;
}

// IF THE BROWSER IS IE11
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident") !== -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:11") !== -1)
{
    showLegalText = false;
}

if (showLegalText) {
    if (lexidTbox.value.length == 0) {
        lexidTbox.className = "quickEnter";
        lexidTbox.value = "ID...";
    }
    if (lexidTbox.value == "ID...")
        lexidTbox.className = "quickEnter";
}
```

});

To be sure, I do not care for this workaround because it's dependent on checking IE versions, but this is the only way I could find to solve this issue.  This prevents the line `Tbox.value = "";` from being run, which avoids the issue I'm having.